# ServletNameNotFound when deploying app to Server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I'am trying to install worklight server in the production server. I'am using :

- Worklight V.6.0
- WAS ND 8.5.5.2
- DB2 10.1.0.2

I have managed to install AppCenter and accessed it. I've run the 'database' and 'install' ant task from 'configure-wasnd-server-db2.xml'.

But when I deployed app to the server and tried to access the Worklight console, I got this following error :

```
8/20/14 10:43:32:721 WIT] 00000099 LocalTranCoor E   WLTC0017E: Resources rolled back due to setRollbackOnly() being called.
[8/20/14 10:43:32:722 WIT] 00000099 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[ServletNameNotFound]: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.getOrCreateAuthenticationContext(AuthenticationContext.java:99)
   at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:119)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3826)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:976)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
   at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
   at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
   at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
   at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
   at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
   at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
   at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
   at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
   at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
   at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
   at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
   at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
   at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
   at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
I cannot find 'adminstall' and 'admdatabases' ant task from the 'configure-wasnd-server-db2.xml'. Do I need these files? Will it cause error if I don't run it? If yes, where can I find these files?

Comment: What is your exact Worklight version and build number?

Comment: @IdanAdar the exact version is 6.0.0.20140519-1131 ..

Comment: Any updates in this question?

Answer (score 0):

Per [this support document](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM80510), the following are possible reasons for this issue:

- Incorrect deployment of project runtime (.war file), for example invalid datasource configuration

Suggestion:

1. Update to the latest available iFix of Worklight 6.0.0.x
2. Follow the [runtime deployment instructions](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/t_transporting_apps_and_adapters.html)